# Conceptual Question about the formal definition of $\bigcap \mathcal F$

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

In Kenneth Kunen's "*The Foundations of Mathematics*, the following definition is provided:

> When $\mathcal F \neq \emptyset$, $$\bigcap \mathcal F = \bigcap_{Y\in \mathcal F}Y=\{x:\forall Y \in \mathcal F(x\in Y)\}$$

Firstly, I will mention that I recognize why we want $\mathcal F \neq \emptyset$ if the formula $\varphi$ we choose to go with is $\varphi:=\forall Y \in \mathcal F (x \in Y)$. Namely, if $\mathcal F = \emptyset$, this formula would be vacuously true so any $x$ would satisfy this formula...and thus all $x$ in our universe would be admitted into the set. The universal set is a contradiction because it contains itself (and by **Axiom of Regularity** and **Pairing Axiom**, this cannot happen).

My question is: How should I encode in First Order Logic the fact that I do not want $\mathcal F$ to equal $\emptyset$?

At first I thought that the correct approach was to replace "$\forall Y \in \mathcal F(x\in Y)$" (which is equivalent to "$\forall Y [Y \in \mathcal F \rightarrow x \in Y]$) with:

$$\forall Y ([\mathcal F = \emptyset \lor Y \in F] \rightarrow x \in Y)$$

This seemed to make sense because if $\mathcal F$ does equal $\emptyset$, the universally quantified statement will be interpreted as a **false** statement (because, for whatever $x$ one choses, $x \notin \emptyset$)...in which case $\bigcap \emptyset = \emptyset$. There is no contradiction here.

However, after looking around on some posts and sites, it seems as though we want to *retain* the fact that $\bigcap \emptyset:= \text{Universal Set}$.

Given this, what is the formal way of encoding Kunen's definition (i.e. stipulating that $\mathcal F \neq \emptyset$)?

Thank you!

Comment: @NoahSchweber I figured as much! For a second you convinced me that all the progress I thought I had made in deciphering FOL was a sham! haha

Comment: See my new answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're observing here is a tension between two approaches to "$\bigcap$:"

1. as a **total** operation, which takes in a set and spits out either a set or the proper class $V$ *(I'm assuming we're working in $\mathsf{ZF}$ or similar, where there is no universal set)*, the latter iff the input is $\emptyset$; or
2. as a **partial** operation, which takes in a set and spits out a set or is undefined, the latter iff the input is $\emptyset$.

Kunen takes approach $(2)$, while some texts/sites take approach $(1)$ *(or work in a framework where a universal set is accepted, in which case you get the best of both worlds but have to leave the $\mathsf{ZF}$-context)*. Certainly it's important for someone starting the subject to understand why the "naive" definition of $\bigcap$ leads to interpretation $(1)$, but approach $(2)$ is more convenient if we're working in first-order logic modified to accommodate partial functions (since at that point we can treat "$\bigcap$" as a genuine function), the issue with $(1)$ being that a proper class is not an "actual object" in the relevant sense. Ultimately there isn't a huge advantage one way or the other.

What you've written is a third alternative:

3. Interpret "$\bigcap$" as a **total** operation, which takes in a set and outputs a set, agreeing with $(1)$ and $(2)$ when the input is nonempty and using a "default value" of $\emptyset$ when the input is $\emptyset$.

In my opinion this is slightly less good: I don't think totality is worth paying the price of actively disagreeing with $(1)$. But this approach will *also* work fine, as long as one is careful to handle the emptyset (which one should be anyways).

Comment: Very cool. So in Kunen's approach, is there a way of symbolically encoding (in FOL) that "$\bigcap \emptyset$" is undefined? i.e. How does one translate the English phrase, "When $\mathcal F = \emptyset$, $\bigcap \mathcal F$ is undefined...but otherwise, use the definition  $\bigcap \mathcal F = \bigcap_{Y\in \mathcal F}Y=\{x:\forall Y \in \mathcal F(x\in Y)\}$" into an FOL statement.

Comment: @S.Cramer There's two ways to do this. One - which I think you **don't** want but I'm listing explicitly for context - is to use a modified version of FOL which accommodates partial functions. The standard approach is to interpret "$t=t$" as true iff $t$ is defined, for a term $t$. So the relevant clause would be "If $x=0$ then $\bigcap x\not=\bigcap x$, and if $x\not=0$ then [usual stuff]." As I said, I don't think that's what you're asking for, but it's worth stating for the record. (One relevant term here is "**free logic**.")

Comment: Lovely. Cheers~

Comment: The second approach, which stays within FOL and I think **is** what you're asking for, is to work with **relations** instead. Consider the formula $\upsilon(x,y)\equiv$ "$x\not=\emptyset$ and $y=\{z:\forall w\in x(z\in w)\}$." The point is that "$\upsilon(x,y)$" is an abbreviation for the version of $\bigcap$ you want. Note that this approach is very general: we can treat *everything* as a relation (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3353180/28111)).